# Replace an input value next to span element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have to this input:

```
<input type="text" id="my_input" />
```

After a user enters anything in the input I have to append this next to the span.

```
<p id="patient_provider" >
  <span>
    Name
  </span>
  Sam
</p>
```

The code I used is(It should be something like below):

```
  $("#patient_provider").html($('#patient_provider').children()[0]+$('#my_input').val());
```

But this is not working.

It is showing something like:

```
[object HTMLSpanElement] Sam
```

Also please note :

There are some css implemented on the span directly and I can not add another span

Comment: Why would you not wrap the "Sam" in a `<span id="name">` and say `$("#name").text($("#my_input").val());` ?

Comment: There are some css implemented on the span directly and I can not add another span

Comment: To say that you cannot change your DOM because of your CSS is just lazy. You are creating a lot more work for yourself by forcing your DOM to be a certain structure by using element and hierarchical selectors in your CSS, rather than adding a class to the span containing "Name" and making your DOM structure independent of your CSS rules and vis-versa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$('#patient_provider').children()[0]` is an element and is converted to a `[object HTMLSpanElement]` string

The right is:

```
 $("#patient_provider").html($('#patient_provider').children()[0].outerHTML+$('#my_input').val());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the ability to change the markup, I would do so.  Something like so - wrapping the place where the name should appear in an element with a useful class.  In this case, I went with a `span` with class `name`:

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="my_input">
<p id="patient_provider" >
  <span>Name</span>
  <span class="name">Sam</span>
</p>
```

Then, your javascript could be improved by doing something like so:

```
// No-conflict-mode-safe document ready
jQuery(function($) {
    // Find the right input based on the name, and bind to keyup
    $('input[name="name"]).on('keyup', function() {
        // Put the value of the input into the span.name element
        $('#patient_provider .name').text($(this).val());
    );
});
```

Comment: There are some css implemented on the span directly and I can not add another span

Comment: Just because there's CSS on the span doesn't mean you can't change the markup.  Add any kind of tag - `em`, `strong` or whatever, and place it in *that* element.  Currently you're doing it the hard way, and creating a lot of limitations and extra work for yourself.

Comment: My guess is that the OP is using either an element selector or a heirarchical selector, or some hellish combination of both! something like `#patient_provider span { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

try this,

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="my_input" />

<p id="patient_provider" >
  <span>
    Name:
  </span>
  <span class="patient_name">
      Sam
  </span>
</p>
```

JS

```
 var patientName = $(".patient_name").text();
 var editedName = false;

 $('#my_input').bind('keydown', function(){
    if(editedName == false){
        $(".patient_name").html($(this).val());
         patientName = $(".patient_name").text();
        editedName = true;
    }
 });

 $('#my_input').bind('keyup', function(){
    if(editedName == true){
            $(".patient_name").text(patientName + $(this).val());
    }
 });
```

JS Fiddle

```
https://jsfiddle.net/guruling/8afzf4dv/
```

Answer (score -3):

The way you have it now, that code is only going to run once. You need to wrap it in an event listener so that it runs whenever a users changes the input or when they click an enter button.